# Jquery code for load more content is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 20 div with same class.
I want to show first 3 div when page is loaded then when click load more it will show another 5 and so on.
I got some basic codes from internet but failed to implement those.

```
var size_item = $('.listing').length();
var v=3;
$('.listing:lt('+v+')').show();
$('#load_more').click(function () {
    v= (v+5 <= size_item) ? v+5 : size_item;
    $('.listing:lt('+v+')').show();
});
```

I'm giving you my fiddle codes [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/tanmndz/jowg34se/)

Comment: Why not doing it by CSS ? Use some meaningful class like `hidden` on your `div.listing` and then remove this class within your Javascript

Comment: Very much thank you for your tips.Actually Below you can see that i got the answer by using Js .But next time i'll remember this .Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
  //show more option
    var size_item = $('.listing').length;
    var v=3;
    $('.listing').hide(); // hide all divs with class `listing`
    $('.listing:lt('+v+')').show();
    $('#load_more').click(function () {
        v= (v+5 <= size_item) ? v+5 : size_item;
        $('.listing:lt('+v+')').show();
        // hide load more button if all items are visible
        if($(".listing:visible").length >= size_item ){ $("#load_more").hide(); }
    });
});
```

```css
.listing{
  color:red;
  border:2px solid black;
  padding:12px;
  margin:8px;
}
.listing:hover{
  background-color:black;
  color:magenta;
}
#load_more{
  color:green;
  background-color:white;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
#load_more:hover{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listing">
 text here 1
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 2
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 3
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 4
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 5
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 6
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 7
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 8
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 9
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 10
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 11
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 12
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 13
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 14
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 15
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 16
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 17
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 18
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 19
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 20
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 21
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 22
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 23
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 24
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 25
</div>
<div class="listing">
 text here 26
</div>
<div id="load_more">
  <center>
    Load More
  </center>
</div>
```

You were almost there. Just a few changes:

1. length is not a function so changed `length()` to `length`
2. initially all the `divs` should be hidden thus the code `$('.listing').hide();` is added which will hide all divs with class `listing` and then on clicking on `#load_more` 5 new items will be shown.
3. load more button will get hidden after 20 or more items are loaded. (implemented by checking the length of visible items)

Comment: thank you for this. The answer is perfect but would you kindly tell me that how to hide the "Load More" text after 20th div ?

Comment: You are welcome. Please check the updated answer where the load more button will get hidden after 20 or more items are loaded. (implemented by checking the length of visible items)

Comment: But can i set that ":last" anyhow? because if the last element's position is 25th then it will be problem.So can it set to last?

Comment: Yes. The code already had the `size_item` variable holding the length of all items. So instead of using 20 we should use that. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#load_more').click(function () {
  var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
  var html = '';
  $.each(data, function(key,val) {
    html += '<div id="load_more">';
    html += '<center>';
    html += 'Load More';
    html += '</center>';
    html += '</div>';
  });
  $('#load_more').append(data);  
});
```